# Receiving "Invalid Date" when attempting to render date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, express

in my CRUD application using Node, Express, MongoDB and EJS as my view engine, I'm encountering an error when attempting to render the date on the Views page. The UI and is outputting "Invalid Date" in the  cell. What am I doing wrong here, as it was functioning correctly when I tested this on repl.it?

From my Controller.js file:

```
//show events
function showEvents(req, res) {
  //get all events
  Event.find({}, (err, events) => {
    if(err) {
      res.status(404);
      res.send('Events not Found');
    }

    let dates = [];

    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      let date = new Date(events[i].date);
      dates.push(date.toDateString());
    };
    console.log(dates);
    //correct data

    // return a view with data
    res.render('pages/events', {
      events: events,
      dates: dates,
      success: req.flash('success')
    });
  });
}
```

From my Events.EJS file:

```
<tbody>

 <% for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= events[i].name %></td>
        <td><%= events[i].description %></td>
        <td><%= dates[i] %></td>
        <td><%= events[i].course %></td>
        <td><%= events[i].slope %></td>
        <td><%= events[i].rating %></td>
        <td><%= events[i].score %></td>
        <td><%= events[i].front %></td>
        <td><%= events[i].back %></td>
        <td>
          <a href="/events/<%= events[i].slug %>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">View</a>
          <a href="/events/<%= events[i].slug %>/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
          <a href="/events/<%= events[i].slug %>/delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% } %>

  </tbody>
```

Comment: You need to console.log(events[i].date) to see what format is being returned. The constructor of Date cannot parse all date formats. You need to make sure the date is returned in the correct format.

Comment: I'm seeing this in terminal, [ 'Invalid Date', 'Invalid Date', 'Invalid Date' ]. But I can't figure what it is that I did wrong with the conversion, because if I write it as events[i].date, it outputs a correct date in mongoDB date format.

Comment: I'm an idiot. The information did not render because I changed the schema within Mongoose as "createdAt" as opposed to "date". Once I made that change, the information rendered accurately.

Comment: I'll guess that `events[i].date` is a string and that it isn't parsed correctly by the *Date* constructor. The golden rule is *never parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse)* as it's largely implementation dependent and inconsistent. Write a small function (2 or 3 lines) to parse the string, or use a library.